# Google Cardboard SDK for Augmented Reality?

Tags: augmented-reality, vuforia, google-cardboard

Is it possible / a good choice to use Google Cardboard SDK to realise AR?I Only have found VR related things with that SDK. What is the best framework for AR? Is Vuforia a good way to go? Im trying to write an AR app (for Android) which detects/scans room numbers at my university and shows the schedule of this room (which class / time / which prof...)
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Cardboard SDK is made for VR, hence not the best option for AR. There are SDKs built specifically for AR. Check out this [comparison](http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/augmented-reality-sdks)

Comment: Thanks that comparison is awesome. The Cardboard SDK isn't even listed there and would surely be a poor choice than like you said. I tried out Vuforia with Unity now and it's pretty straight forward so far.

Answer (score 1):

There is an alpha version of DroidScript (JavaScript IDE for Android) available which supports augmented reality for Google Cardboard.  There is also a sample on the DroidScript forum that demonstrates Aruco marker detection (Augmented reality).  So I guess you could hack something together quite easily if you ask the developers for the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of vuforia can be integrated with Google cardboard. 
Check this link:
https://developer.vuforia.com/library/articles/Solution/Integrating-Cardboard-SDK-050

Comment: Link  only answers are discouraged, since if the link changes the info is lost.  Its best to post the relevant details....

Comment: Link is dead :/